# Python does not release memory after using pickle.load()

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, pickle

I want to load a big pickled file to my `python` project. The file size is about `4GB`. After using `pickle.load(file)`, the used memory of about `10GB` will not be released.

This is my code:

```
import pickle
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

# function to load the project file
def LoadProject(file_path):
    with open(file_path[0], 'rb') as file:
        LoadedFile = pickle.load(file)
            
    return LoadedFile

# load project
file_path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Load Project", "", "Pickle file (*.pkl)")

File = LoadProject(file_path)
```

Do you have any ideas on how to free the `memory`?

Comment: You can assign the File object with None. Still, for such large files it's a bad practice to load the entire file in memory.

Comment: When exactly do you mean? I could just assign the file object with None before running the function. But this would not change anything. The memory will not be released after i run the line "pickle.load(file)".

Comment: How could it be released if the function must return a reference to that object. When you will need the memory released you can assign a None to the "File" variable.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not formulated clearly (sorry for that). I want to keep the "File" variable to do further work with, but the file size is about 4GB and i have a memory usage of about 10GB. I want to release the remaining 6GB of memory.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. I'm afraid you cannot do that. Typically python objects take more memory than its raw binary data, but the overhead should not be so large that it doubles your data. Unless you have a whole lot of really small objects/dicts, then the overhead adds up quickly.
What kind of data are you unpickling?

Comment: The file is a dictionary with different data types in it. I have overall 15 objects within the dict (list, dict, set, float, boolean). Within these objects are stored custom class objects, numpy arrays, trimesh objects. So a lot of different types and sometimes a lot of small objects.

Comment: I have similar issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74086883/pickle-dump-writes-to-file-but-does-not-return Do you have a solution?